# Why does the V1 list change? Why is it "linked"?

Tags: python, list

```
V0 = [0]
V1 = V0

V0[0] = 2

print(f"V0: {V0}")
print(f"V1: {V1}")
```

Comment: V0 and V1 hold the same reference to the value.

Comment: Python uses references, if you'd like a copy of V0, use `copy()`

Comment: Right.  There is only one list in your program.  That list happens to be bound to two names.  This is one of the classic Python blunders.  https://github.com/timrprobocom/documents/blob/main/UnderstandingPythonObjects.md